# How to re-use external project in cmake subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I have a *cmake*-based project with the following structure:

```
Project A
|---lib B
|---lib C
```

All 3 projects (`A`, `B`, and `C`) have their `CMakeLists.txt`, and I include `lib B` and `lib C` in `project A` by `add_subdirectory` command.

I also have `project D` as a dependency for all my 3 projects (`A`, `B`, and `C`), and I'd like to use it by `ExternalProject_Add` command.

Is there any way to include it only into one project, i. e. can I build `project D` only once in one of these projects, and re-use it in others? Now I simply include `project D` as external project in all my 3 projects, but it seems weird for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every project may check existence of some variable(or target). If variable(target) exists, then the project uses it as reference to the `projectD`, otherwise the project creates local `projectD` with `ExternalProject_Add`:

**libB/CMakeLists.txt**, **libC/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
if(NOT TARGET projectD)
    # If `projectD` is not created by upper level, create it locally
    ExternalProject_Add(projectD ...)
endif()
# Get properties of the external project, which are needed for linking.
ExternalProject_Get(projectD prop1 ... )
# Use properties
...
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
ExternalProject_Add(projectD ...)

add_subdirectory(libB) # libB will use our projectD's installation
add_subdirectory(libC) # libC will use our projectD's installation
...
```